# SwiftUI - My blended Image view is failing on iPhone. Works in preview

Tags: swiftui

I have a background view that is made up of two images. They are masked to create transparent gradients to cross-fade between them.  When I run the blend without the masks, it works on iPhone, but when I try it with the masks, only the top layer shows.  My code is below:

```
struct BackgroundImageForBlending: View {
    enum imageSide {
        case left, right
    }
    var side: imageSide

    var imageName: String

    func selectImage() -> some View {
        switch side {
        case .left:
            return Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75)
                .clipped()
                .mask(Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)
                    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, .white, .white]), startPoint: .trailing, endPoint: .leading)))
                .padding(.trailing, UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.25)
        case .right:
            return Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75)
                .clipped()
                .mask(Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)
                    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, .white, .white]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)))
                .padding(.leading, UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.25)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        selectImage()
    }
}


struct BlendedRaceClassBackgroundImage: View {
    var champion: Champion

    func findRaceImage() -> String {
        return champion.race.race.map {$0.race.lowercased()} ?? ""
    }

    func findClassImage() -> String {
        champion.characterClass.characterClass.map {"\($0.name.lowercased())_\(champion.gender!.rawValue)"} ?? ""
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            BackgroundImageForBlending(side: .left, imageName: findRaceImage())
            BackgroundImageForBlending(side: .right, imageName: findClassImage())
                .blendMode(.multiply)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
    }
}
```

[image: view in preview]
[image: view on iPhone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  I solved my own question.  It wasn't the mask that was creating the issue.  It was dark mode on the iPhone.  The black background was causing the issue.  I added a Rectangle to the ZStack behind the blendedImage and everything worked.